# Content overflows when JavaScript is used to adjust div height, before it is it used to adjust div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Content overflows when JavaScript is used to adjust the div height, before it is it used to adjust the div content, if the adjusted div content is higher than the adjusted div height. This does not happen when JavaScript is not used to adjust the div height.

Basically, 2 divs are side by side, and the shorter div is adjusted to the height of the taller div. Then when a button is clicked, content is filled in the original shorter div, but the content overflows, if the content is higher than the adjusted div height. How can we fix this?

```
<?php
  include("ajaxLink.php");
?>

<style>
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1000px;
}
div:not(#wrapper) {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
#content2 {
  vertical-align: top;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>

<button onclick = 'fillContent2()'> Click me </button><br><br>
<div id = 'wrapper'>
  <div id = 'content1'> 
    content1content1content1content1content1 
    content1content1content1content1content1 
  </div>
<div id = 'content2'>content2</div>
</div>

<script>

$(function(){

  var height = getHeight("#content1");
  setHeight("#content2", height, "px");

});

function fillContent2() {
  $("#content2").html(
    "content2content2content2content2content2<br>"+
    "content2content2content2content2content2<br>"+
    "content2content2content2content2content2"
  );
} //end of function fillContent2()

function getHeight(name) {
  var height = $(name).height();
  return height;
} //end of function getWidth(name)

function setHeight(name,height,type) {
  $(name).css("height", height + type);
} //end of function setHeight(name,height,type)

</script>
```

Comment: Are overflow: hidden; or overflow: auto; options? On the problem div.

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen No, I want the default results.