# Set inline-blocks with the same height, without specifying height, using absolute positioning, nor JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I need to have 2 inline-blocks next to each other, and I need the height of the second div to be the same height of the first div, but there's a few things that I can't have.

1. Heights cannot be specified for either divs.
2. The second div cannot be absolute positioned.
3. JavaScript cannot be used to set the position of the second div.

Right now, I'm using absolute positioning for the second div to make it the same height as the first div. Is there a way to do it without using that, number 1 or number 3?

```css
#wrapper {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 50%;
position: relative;
}
#content1 {
border: 1px solid blue;
display: inline-block;
width: 40%;
}
#content2 {
border: 1px solid blue;
display: inline-block;
width: 40%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

```html
<div id = 'wrapper'>
<div id = 'content1'> content1<br>content1 </div>
<div id = 'content2'> content2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, can Javascript be used to set the height?

Comment: These seem a strange combination of restrictions. Is there any _technical_ reason why these are in place, or is this just for fun/homework?

Comment: Does the display of the content divs have to be inline-block?

Comment: @Rhumborl Well, it's related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524400/content-overflows-when-javascript-is-used-to-adjust-div-height-before-it-is-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex box to achieve this. Setting `flex:0.4` will behave the same as `width:40%`.

Note that all versions of Internet Explorer [don't play well with flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) tho.

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
}

#content1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0.4;
}

#content2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='content1'>content1<br>content1</div>
  <div id='content2'>content2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Super. Awesome. Great. I love it.

Comment: @Rhumborl - might be cool if you can explain more why this works? Would help a lot of folks new to flex box

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two options: flexbox and tables.

**Flexbox**

Flexible boxes provide a way to stretch flex items via the default [`align-self: stretch`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-stretch)

> Its used value is the length necessary to make the [cross size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#cross-size) of
>   the item’s margin box as close to the same size as the line as
>   possible, while still respecting the constraints imposed by
>   min-height/min-width/max-height/max-width.

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}
#content1, #content2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='content1'>content1<br />content1</div>
  <div id='content2'>content2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS tables**

This is much less flexible but is older (CSS2.1), so it is more widely supported. Table-cells in the same row are stretched to have the same height.

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
}
#inner-wrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
#inner-wrapper:after {
  content: ''; /* Fills remaining space */
}
#content1, #content2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='inner-wrapper'>
    <div id='content1'>content1<br />content1</div>
    <div id='content2'>content2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```